# Delete the listitems from database

Tags: android

How to delete the list items from listview contact adapter class and Sqlite database.From listview it deleted successfully.But in database it doesn't delete.if I call the delete method means it shows null ponter exception.And my Listview is in Fragment class and list items are in listview contact adapter class.on that I'm having 2 buttons(Update,Delete).If i click the delete means listiems should be delete in database.Please refer the below codes and share your ideas
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0fnb9779yf4ra4/DatabaseHandler.java?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qijcvgxbnq5jj72/ListviewContactAdapter.java?dl=0

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: final int temp = position;

           holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {



    db.Delete_Contact(id);    

   ListviewContactAdapter.listContact.remove(position);
    
              notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: (in DATABASEHANDLER)public  void Delete_Contact(int id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = " +String.valueOf(id),null );
  db.close();
  }

Comment: and the listview is in fragment class

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0fnb9779yf4ra4/DatabaseHandler.java?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ab0f0bwxt33j1l/TodaysTask.java?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qijcvgxbnq5jj72/ListviewContactAdapter.java?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

1 - First off all delete your row form database.

2 - Delete row from listView (adapter Data)

3 - Now call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.

Comment: Ya listview items are deleted.while calling the database delete method it shows runtime error,And listview is in fragment.

Comment: can u give yr mail id.I'll share my code.becoz code length is too long

Comment: upload it on dropbox and share link with me